# Write credentials to 1password with ansible

Tags: ansible, password

I was hoping somebody knows if it's possible to put credentials in 1password by ansible?

I found a module [onepassword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/onepassword.html), but it is only for getting data from 1password. I need something that allows writing data to 1password.

Do you know any options?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link in your question](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/onepassword.html) points to a lookup plugin. There is also a [raw lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/onepassword_raw.html) as well as a [module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/onepassword_info_module.html#onepassword-info-module).

Note that the lookups, as all other lookups, will only run on the ansible controller, not on the target host. The module will run on the machine you are managing.

Meanwhile none of those are able to create an object in onepassword (for time being ?). But since the use of the lookups/module is conditionned to the availability of the `op` command line, why don't you pass a command to it directly with the ansible command module ?

I found [the documentation for this](https://support.1password.com/command-line/#create-an-item). It is not straightforward but look rather easy (just a json file to create first).